Not the same path between anaconda/python3 and Visual Studio Code
Introduction.
I have the following paths and versions of python 3 and conda:
% python3 --version
Python 3.12.4

% where python3
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

 % conda --version
conda 24.7.1

% conda info --envs                                         
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/anaconda3
                         /usr/local/anaconda3

I would like to use Visual Studio Code to run the python scripts, and the python default interpreter path in Visual Studio Code is the following:
python default interpreter path: /usr/local/bin/python3

When I run just a simple command on Visual Studio Code, like
import numpy as np

I get the following error message:
% /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/batman/Desktop/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/batman/Desktop/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Question.
Should I change the python default interpreter path in Visual Studio Code, in order to make the python script work? If Yes, which path should I use?

This question is similar to: Anaconda not installing on mac—conda not found. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you check your PATH?

In Visual Studio Code, by replacing the python default interpreter path
/usr/local/bin/python3 

with
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3

the code worked!

To the person who put a "-1", why? Explain the reason why of a "-1". That solution greatly works!
